# Litespeed error : Table name must be specified in the format owner_name.table_name

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, litespeed

I'm trying to recover a table from Litespeed bakcup. The table is of schema SOURCE. Litespeed object recovery wizard fails with the error:: Table name must be specified in the format owner_name.table_name. I tried with the store procedure directly as well but it's giving the same error. Please help me fix this issue:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_objectrecovery 
@filename = 'backup_file_name'  
, @filenumber = 1
, @objectname = 'SOURCE.target_rpt_2016'
, @destinationdatabase = 'database_name' 
,@destinationtable ='SOURCE.target_rpt_2016_restore'
, @tempdirectory = 'recovery_temp_dir'
```

I tried giving destinationtable without schema/dbo as well but it's throwing same error.

Comment: What the error says?

Comment: It's old man :D
I look in the google and I found this. Take a look
http://documents.software.dell.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/7.5/netvault-litespeed-for-sql-server-user-guide/use-extended-stored-procedures/xp_objectrecovery

Comment: @Krismorte Error says: Table name must be specified in the format owner_name.table_name

Comment: @Krismorte I've taken the Sp and paramaters from that site only.I have updated my statement in the question.  I want to know if i'm missing anything.

Comment: Just one more question. What is the edition that you is running this command?

Comment: @Krismorte Enterprise edition. We have recovered lot of tables from the same server DBs. I guess there is some issue while recovering tables with schema other than dbo which i'm not able to figure out

Comment: SOURCE schame exists in the destinantio db? Try dbo

Comment: @Krismorte Yes. I'm trying to recover the table in the same datanase only. Thank you for your support Kris. I have figured out the issue. Please take a look at my answer. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast figured out the issue.

The owner of the schema Source is a domain account Dom\AXp0101. So when I changed the paramter  @ObjectName to '[Dom\AXp0101].[source].[2016_target_rpt_2016]' the recovery completed. Read somewhere that as the owner of this particular schema is a domain account, there might be issues associated with demiliters so we have exclusively specify like above.